# Datatables - after first button click the button is no longer responsive in each row. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, datatables, mapbox

I have a datatable called skiTable.  It consists of rows of ski mountains.  In each row, there is a button called `FlyTo` with latitude and longitude (`aa_x`, `aa_y`).  When clicked it zooms into the ski mountain using mapbox gl js (`map.flyTo`).  Once the map is zoomed in, I then use `map.queryRenderedFeatures()` to return data to datatable of just the displayed mountain in `aDemoItems`.  Sometimes there can be surrounding mountains and therefore the row count can be anywhere from 1 mountain to 10 mountains.

On the first initiation of the datatable, clicking the `FlyTo` button works fine, however, none of the buttons work after the first click.  Dead.  Here is the button's click event handler;

```
        $('#ski_index').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var data = skiTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            x = data.properties["aa_x"];
            y = data.properties["aa_y"]
            map.flyTo({center: [x, y], zoom: 15});
        });
```

Again, the data for the datatable comes via mapbox's `map.queryRenderedFeatures()` which is stringified (`JSON.stringify(uniqueFeatures)`) and passed to datatables as data:           `aDemoItems`.

```
let skiTable =      $('#ski_index').DataTable({
            stateSave:      true,
            stateDuration:  60 * 60 * 48, // save the state for 2 days.
            responsive:     true,
            info:           true,
            destroy:        true,
            data:           aDemoItems,
            dataType:       'json', 
            "columns": [{
                    data: "properties.name",
                    "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>",
                    render: function (data, type, row){
                        return '<button>FlyTo</button>'
                    }
                }];
           });
```

Everything works well except any second click on the button `FlyTo` doesn't respond.  As I zoom in and out of the map, the datatable shows only the ski mountains displayed.  Any help much appreciated to get the button working from the second click.

I just realized this is a error message on the second click of the `FlyTo` button as follows;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
```

If I add console.log(row) to the column definition as follows;

```
                {
                    data: "properties.name",
                    "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>",
                    render: function (data, type, row){
                        console.log(row);
                        return '<button>Click!</button>'
                    }
                },
```

... the `console.log(row)` does show `properties` with values in `aa_x` and and `aa_y`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try not to use the table destroy methods, which in my experience cause more problems than they solve, and are rarely needed unless you want to change some of the table structure, such as the number of columns.

Instead make use of the `ajax.reload()` method to refresh the data in your table. You say that your data is coming from an external source, which likely means you cannot directly apply it to your table. To solve this, define your `ajax` property in the table options as a function like this (also store your table as a variable):

```js
let my_array = [];

const skiTable = $('#ski_index').DataTable({
    ajax: function(data, callback) {
        callback({ data: my_array })
    }
});
```

Next grab your data, do whatever ajdustments you need to do to it, and store the results in `my_array`.

```js
my_array = some_new_data;
```

Now you can call the `reload()` function to refresh the data in your DataTable

```js
skiTable.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: the data is not being load with ajax so reload will not work.

Comment: @spreaderman Perhaps I did not explain myself properly. If you update a local javascript array with some new data, you can use the `ajax.reload()` function to refresh your table as I explained above. You don't need to actually use Ajax.

Comment: So how would you reload if the data is not ajax? The data comes from aDemoData = map.queryRenderedFeatures(); which is triggered each time the map zooms in and out and retrurns the data in view.  Possible to show more code how that would work please?

Comment: I think I am getting you now.  Sorry.                  ajax:           function(data, callback) {
                                    callback({ data: aDemoItems })
                                }, works to bring in the data.  I placed   skiTable.ajax.reload(); in   $('#ski_index tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {} at the end but get same error DataTables warning: table id=ski_index - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Answer (score 0):

It seen this line  `var data = skiTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();` caused the error because "data" is undefined, Did you try destroy and reinitialize whole the datatable like this https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/44956/how-to-destroy-and-reinitialize-the-datatable

Comment: Thanks. Why would data be undefined there? Not sure where to clear and destroy and initialize. I tried var tableId = "#skiTable"; if(skiTable!=null){ skiTable.clear(); skiTable.destroy(); } $(skiTable + " tbody").empty(); $(skiTable + " thead").empty(); let skiTable = $('#ski_index').DataTable({... But of course I get Cannot access 'skiTable' before initialization. Any ideas. thank you.

Comment: //Destroy the old Datatable
$('#skiTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();

//Create new Datatable
$('#skiTable').DataTable({...})

Comment: I have //Destroy the old Datatable   $('#skiTable').DataTable().clear().destroy(); 
 $('#ski_index').DataTable({...}) but get error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties').  No getting how this is to work unfo.

Comment: you try logging by console $('#ski_index').DataTable() to data

Comment: Cannot get it working.  Where would I put the destroy code?

Comment: @spreaderman when you update data of DataTable

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I took parts of both mark_b and buithienquyet and some other suggestion from datatables forum to make a solution.  I changed the datatables source to ajax as per buithienquyet's suggestion and used $('#ski_index').DataTable().ajax.reload();  In the click handled I needed to add 'off' as follows:  $('#ski_index tbody').off( 'click', 'button').on( 'click', 'button', function () {}.

Answer (score -1):

Use safe operator `?.properties?.name` if possible

Javascript now supports safe operator.
[image]

or If you can use function instead of string and pass parameters:

```
...
data: (params) => {
    if(params) {
        return "properties?.name";
    }
},
...
```

Comment: sorry, not understand you comment.  The problem I have is that the first time I click a button, it works but the second time not.